# App Store version of my app is not working correctly

Tags: ios, spritebuilder

I released a game a few days ago which I won't name because of this very unusual issue it's having. It's essentially a game where you're falling through a bunch of random obstacles and collect coins along the way to buy stuff later on.

The game worked perfectly fine on my phone when testing it from Xcode, there were absolutely no issues with it when it was completed and I was happy with the product when I submitted it. Today I downloaded my own app from the app store, 3 days after I released it. I noticed this very unusual issue where my character dies randomly in mid-air, he does not collide with anything.

It usually happens when grabbing a coin, but it's not consistent, it can happen to the second coin, third or even tenth coin. I'm also noticing the physics body for some obstacles as well as the character is off sometimes, only sometimes. This causes the character to die much sooner than he would have when getting close to an object.

I cannot figure out the cause of this issue and I'm stressing out because of the time I invested in this. The game works perfectly fine on my phone when running off of Xcode and this unusual behaviour does not occur at all, but the app store version seems to be very buggy. Does anyone know what could be the probable cause of this? I'd also like to mention that I used SpriteBuilder to make this game.

Comment: Did you upload a testing version to iTunes Connect and then download it to your device, or did you only install from Xcode, or did you only run while actually connected to Xcode?

Comment: I only installed it from Xcode when testing it. I did not upload it to iTunes Connect and download it from TestFlight to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app store version is identical in every way with the builds you can upload to TestFlight. So you should upload a new build there and see if you can reproduce the issue.

It is possible that you are experiencing a problem where the compiler's optimisation has introduced a rare bug which you were not seeing "on your device" because when you do a Debug build there is no optimisation active.

TestFlight builds are Release builds (from Build&Archive) and thus have compiler optimisations enabled. You can also disable them to verify that the problem does not happen then.

If you are able to show the problem in Release mode and not in Debug mode then you should file a call with Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS) after filing a [bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try those options. I never actually used TestFlight to test the app and was instead only using Xcode.

Comment: You can simply turn on optimisations for your build&run builds... although that messes with the debugging. But for verifying that this is the culprit it would work too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was able to reproduce the problem in Release mode. Unfortunately, disabling compiler optimization did not fix the issue, not sure what may be causing this within Release mode but it's good to know that it only occurs within Release and it's not related to anything else.

Comment: I guess the only thing you could do now is to add many NSLog statements around the place where you expect the problem to occur and try to conclude from that what might be the bug and whether it is yours or Apple's.